# Printing output in console.log for a function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a javascript that I am using to pull id of a tag . But due to some limitation on a platform where I need to use this I have to make this script under function so I will get the output in return. I am trying but I am failing to get it.

This is the script I have;

```
var arr2st3 = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('article:nth-child(-n+4)'), function(el) {
    return el.id.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
});
```

This is what I am trying to come up;

```
function myfun() {
var arr2st3 = []
var arr2st3 = arr2st3.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('article:nth-child(-n+4)'), 
        function(el) {
        return el.id.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
    });
    return;
        console.log(myfun);

}
```

This is the test url -> https://jsfiddle.net/v3d0nz9d/

I need to get output in return as **['123456', '7896669', '1147777']**

Any help would be highly appreciated. 
TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[].map` is shorthand for `Array.prototype.map`, so you don't need to store that in a variable, you can just return the return value of your `map`. Anything after a `return` statement won't be called, so your `console.log` is never reached. Also, to log the values returned from your function, you need to call it in your `console.log`.

```
function myfun() {
  return [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('article:nth-child(-n+4)'), function(el) {
    return el.id.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
  });
}

console.log(myfun());
```

Comment: ah okay I got it @Lee thank you for fixing my script. Really appreciate your help. thanks